# How do you calculate values using inputs that were created with loops in php?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a calculator where the user enters numbers in different sections, the numbers in each section get multiplied by certain number depending on the section, then it all gets added up to one total value. For example, if the multiplier for section 1 and 2 were 5 and 10 respectively, and the inputs for section 1 were 2 and 3, and section 2 was 5 and 6, the total would be 10+15+50+60=135.

The problem  is that the multipliers, numbers of sections, and amount of inputs per section change depending on what link the user clicks on because there will be many calculators which all do the same thing, just different amounts of things.

I have tried making different calculator pages with fixed variables and that's simple enough, but I want to make this work with one dynamic page, and having hundreds of pages which do something so similar would be extremely redundant. The next thing that comes to mind is using a database, but nothing needs to be saved, and I'm just making a simple calculation so there must be an easier way. I have a simplified version of my code here just to illustrate my problem.

How do I work with the numbers that the user inputs?

Index page:

```
<a href="calculator.php?sections=2">Two</a><br>
<a href="calculator.php?sections=3">Three</a>
```

Calculator page:

```
$sections = $_GET['sections'];


if ($sections == 2) {
    $s1visibility = '';
    $s2visibility = '';
    $s3visibility = 'none';
    $s1inputs = '2';
    $s2inputs = '4';
    $s1multiplier = '5';
    $s2multiplier = '10';
}

if ($sections == 3) {
    $s1visibility = '';
    $s2visibility = '';
    $s3visibility = '';
    $s1inputs = '2';
    $s2inputs = '3';
    $s3inputs = '4';
    $s1multiplier = '3';
    $s2multiplier = '6';
    $s3multiplier = '9';
}

?>

<div style='display: <?php echo $s1visibility ?>'> Section 1<br>
        <?php
            for ($x=0; $x < $s1inputs; $x++) {
                echo '<input type="number"><br>';
            }
        ?>
</div>

<div style='display: <?php echo $s2visibility ?>'> Section 2<br>
        <?php
            for ($x=0; $x < $s2inputs; $x++) {
                echo '<input type="number"><br>';
            }
        ?>
</div>

<div style='display: <?php echo $s3visibility ?>'> Section 3<br>
        <?php
            for ($x=0; $x < $s3inputs; $x++) {
                echo '<input type="number"><br>';
            }
        ?>
</div>

<form action='' method='post'><input type='submit' value='Find value' name='findvalue'></form>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['findvalue'])) {

}

?>
```

Comment: I just want to be clear. There are pre-defined number of inputs for each section, depending on the number of sections available, right?

Comment: Does section 2 only multiply by 10? What's the point of this anyways? If you give every Element the same name like `name='someName[]'` then and set `multiple` to `multiple='multiple'` in your HTML attributes, and you're using `method='post'` in your form, then you can loop over `$_POST['someName']`, *(which would be an Array)* with a `foreach` loop. You really should use AJAX anyways.

Comment: @user01 Yes. If anyone knows a way to just echo the numbers that the user inputs after pressing the button, that works too. I just need to know some way of accessing them.